# Is it possible to use Custom Issue Type as Epic in JIRA Agile

Tags: jira, jira-agile

We already have set of IssueTypes and are following Agile Scrum.

Now, we're planning to use JIRA Agile. It is mentioned in JIRA Documentation that EPIC is an issue of Type "Epic". But, since we're a considerably sized BU with few projects - we would like to use the "New Feature" Issue Type as Epic - so the Spec, Dev and Test can be added to the "Feature" Epic.

Question is: Is it possible to use Custom Issue Type as Epic in JIRA Agile? If so, How?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the use case correctly but I'm just curious why you don't want to use Epic issue type and convert issues with type New Feature from existing projects to Epics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no.

The `Epic` issue type (and a few others) are added to a base JIRA installation when you install the "JIRA Agile" extension/plugin. None of the features (Epic Links, Epics filtering on backlogs, Epic burndown charts, etc) will work with any other issue type.

I'd suggest you begin adapting your process to use the new issue type.

Now, there's nothing stopping you associating custom fields (if that's what you use for Spec, Dev, and Test information) with the Epic issue type so you get the same functionality you have with New Feature.

Comment: Thank you. This is what we tried with a small internal project. But, I thought why not JIRA support other issue types.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the Epic type created by Jira Agile (note that already created schemes remember the old name) to any name and it works.

I guess, there would be hack in DB and reassign issue type to Jira Agile somewhere in DB but who knows what tables are linked to [see some description here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-administrator-s-guide/jira-agile-jira-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

the functionality behind Epics in Jira is really useful, its a shame that you cant create multiple issue types with this type of functionality.

We would like to manage our refinement process using a 'Requirement' task that is defined as an Epic issue type as well as manage our delivery process using a 'New Feature' task defined as an Epic issue type.

We could use simply use Epics for both and distinguish a refinement task from a delivery task by naming them appropriately, but this would not allow us to define a different workflow for Requirements & New Features which is essential.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).